# update function is not working as expected in dataweave 2?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I would like to update one line in my incoming payload. The field is 'price'.
My dataweave  scripet is

```
%dw 2.0

output application/json

---

payload.IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization.items.item update 
{

    case  price at .price -> "100"
}
```

My Payload is;

```
    {
        "IntegrationEntities": {
            "integrationEntity": [
                {
                    "integrationEntityHeader": {
                        "integrationTrackingNumber": "XXXX",
                        "referenceCodeForEntity": "132804",
                        "additionalInfo": "ADDITIONALINFO"
                    },
                    "integrationEntityDetails": {
                        "contractUtilization": {
                            "externalId": "417145",
                            "utilizationType": "INVOICE",
                            "isDelete": "No",
                            "documentNumber": "132804",
                            "documentDescription": "",
                            "documentDate": "2021-03-26",
                            "totalSpendAmount": ".92",
                            "documentCurrency": "AUD",
                            "createdBy": "Oracle Integration",
                            "status": "FULLY PAID",
                            "items": {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_1",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": ".92",
                                        "lineAmount": ".92",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    },
 {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_2",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804_2",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": ".95",
                                        "lineAmount": ".95",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

But above script always returning with the income payload price as '.92'

The output I get is;

```
    [
      [
        {
          "lineItemId": "132804_1",
          "contractNumber": "XXXXXX",
          "contractLineId": "",
          "lineNumber": "1",
          "name": "132804",
          "description": "132804",
          "quantity": "1",
          "price": ".92",
          "lineAmount": ".92",
          "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYY",
          "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
        },
,
    {
      "lineItemId": "132804_2",
      "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
      "contractLineId": "",
      "lineNumber": "1",
      "name": "132804",
      "description": "132804_2",
      "quantity": "1",
      "price": ".95",
      "lineAmount": ".95",
      "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
      "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
    }
      ]
    ]
```

What is wrong with my script? Why it is not updating my price value? and why i get the partial payload as output?
My requirement is, update the price amount and give the full payload as output.

Comment: You are probably missing the index for occurrence in the array.

Comment: @SalimKhan What is that? I try above in the online dataweave tool . https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
   case item at .IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[0].integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization.items.item[0] -> item   update {
       case price at .price -> "100"
   }
}
```

Updating the answer per your requirement:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {

case .IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[0].integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization.items.item -> $ map {
    ($ update {
          case .price -> if ($ as Number < 1) "0" ++ $ else $
    }
    )}
}
```

Comment: Thank you that works,, So if I have array of elements how can i provide that index?Eg: Item is an array, so there will be multiple 'price' element so above indexing wont wrok?

Comment: Can you please provide a new question with a sample input and expected output or update your question with the same? Hopefully the above answered your ask..

Comment: I have edited my input with teh array of inputs.

Comment: Input and corresponding output as well ?

Comment: Do you want all price keys to be updated to "100" ?

Comment: No, there will be an if condition, if value is less than "1", i need to append "0." infront, else the value as it is.. But, my update is not working, so i didnt want to put my "if condition there

Comment: You can iterate on the item array and use `case` to update the `price` element as apt.

Comment: I have added another question here after following your answer. It would be great if you kindly provide an answer, what is wrong in my script? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449976/dataweave2-update-function-for-few-entries-not-working