# Dataweave2 Update function for few entries not working?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I want to update 3 fields in my Array of paylaod.

- TotalSpendamount
- price
- lineAmount.

My script is as follows;

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update {
    case .IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity -> $ map {
        ($ update {
            case .integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization.items.item ->  $ map {
                ($ update {
                    case .price -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
          case .lineAmount -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                })
            }
    
    case totalSpendAmount at .integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization ->   totalSpendAmount update
    {
                case  totalSpendAmount at .totalSpendAmount -> if ( totalSpendAmount as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ totalSpendAmount else totalSpendAmount
            }
        })
    }
}
```

If I run above script, only `totalspendAmount`' is getting update.If I remove the '`totalspendAmount`' case block, my '`price` and `lineamount` fields are updating correctly.
What is wrong in my script?

My payload is;

```
      {
        "IntegrationEntities": {
            "integrationEntity": [
                {
                    "integrationEntityHeader": {
                        "integrationTrackingNumber": "XXXX",
                        "referenceCodeForEntity": "132804",
                        "additionalInfo": "ADDITIONALINFO"
                    },
                    "integrationEntityDetails": {
                        "contractUtilization": {
                            "externalId": "417145",
                            "utilizationType": "INVOICE",
                            "isDelete": "No",
                            "documentNumber": "132804",
                            "documentDescription": "",
                            "documentDate": "2021-03-26",
                            "totalSpendAmount": ".92",
                            "documentCurrency": "AUD",
                            "createdBy": "Oracle Integration",
                            "status": "FULLY PAID",
                            "items": {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_1",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": ".92",
                                        "lineAmount": ".92",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    },
 {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_2",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804_2",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": ".95",
                                        "lineAmount": ".95",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

The output I look for is;

```
  {
        "IntegrationEntities": {
            "integrationEntity": [
                {
                    "integrationEntityHeader": {
                        "integrationTrackingNumber": "XXXX",
                        "referenceCodeForEntity": "132804",
                        "additionalInfo": "ADDITIONALINFO"
                    },
                    "integrationEntityDetails": {
                        "contractUtilization": {
                            "externalId": "417145",
                            "utilizationType": "INVOICE",
                            "isDelete": "No",
                            "documentNumber": "132804",
                            "documentDescription": "",
                            "documentDate": "2021-03-26",
                            "totalSpendAmount": "0.92",
                            "documentCurrency": "AUD",
                            "createdBy": "Oracle Integration",
                            "status": "FULLY PAID",
                            "items": {
                                "item": [
                                    {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_1",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": "0.92",
                                        "lineAmount": "0.92",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    },
 {
                                        "lineItemId": "132804_2",
                                        "contractNumber": "YYYYYYY",
                                        "contractLineId": "",
                                        "lineNumber": "1",
                                        "name": "132804",
                                        "description": "132804_2",
                                        "quantity": "1",
                                        "price": "0.95",
                                        "lineAmount": "0.95",
                                        "purchaseOrderNumber": "YYYYYY",
                                        "purchaseOrderDescription": ""
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this script:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity.integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization map ((cu, index) -> cu  update {
        case .totalSpendAmount if ($ as Number < 1) -> "0" ++ $
        case .items.item -> $ map {
            ($ update {
                    case .price -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                    case .lineAmount -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                })
            }
})
```

Updated Scripts:

**Approach 1**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---


payload update  {
    case .IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity -> $ map {
     ($ update {
            case .integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization-> $ update {
                        case .totalSpendAmount -> if ($ as Number < 1)  "0" ++ $ else $
                        case .items.item -> $ map ((cuItem,index) -> cuItem  update {
                                            case .price -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                                            case .lineAmount -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                })
            }                                                                                                
         }                                                                                                       )}                                                                                                                                      
}
```

**Approach 2**

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload update  {
    case .IntegrationEntities.integrationEntity[0].integrationEntityDetails.contractUtilization-> $ update {
                        case .totalSpendAmount -> if ($ as Number < 1)  "0" ++ $ else $
                        case .items.item -> $ map ((cuItem,index) -> cuItem  update {
                                            case .price -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                                            case .lineAmount -> if ( $ as Number < 1 ) "0" ++ $ else $
                })
            }                                                                                                
         }
```

Comment: Thank you That works..But Could you please explain me what is wrong in my script? and what is the difference in you script?

Comment: I miss the whole payload as the output in the above script..

Comment: Didn't get to it till today. I have updated the answer with a couple of ways to achieve what you wanted to..

Comment: Thanks a lot.. approach 1 is the one i was looking for..Figured out my script error too